Auto create pictures in doxygen using the references generated
Using doxygen, v.1.12.0 for generate uml pictures or similiar.
All code is in plain C.
Anyone knows if its possible to get like a easy picture showing input and output data per function documented using its "references".
Example:
From doxygen output:
References mInput1, mInput2, and mOutput1.

This is clickable variables mInput1,2 and mOutput1 within a function in C (doxygen generated).
I want it automatically to be like for example:

Anyone know if this is possible in a easy way or have any ideas on how using auto using doxygen?

Within doxygen there is no possibility to show graphically the input and output parameters (how would parameters that are input and output represented / specified ?). Maybe you could make something based on the doxygen XML output.

Yeah good Q, and I thought so also, just wanted to check if any ideas exists then, using xml output could be good suggestion.


Anyone know if this is possible in a easy way or have any ideas on how using auto using doxygen?

refer to Doxygen Configuration, and other documentations
Step 1. Install Graphviz
For Linux:
> apt-get install graphviz

For Windows, just download Graphviz from the official site.
Step 2. Customize Doxygen Configuration file
HAVE_DOT = YES
CALL_GRAPH = YES
CALLER_GRAPH = YES
UML_LOOK = YES
DOT_IMAGE_FORMAT = svg
INTERACTIVE_SVG = YES
COLLABORATION_GRAPH = YES


Can you give an example where the function and the variables as indicated in the question show up?
